# How do I format an HTML url that doesn't have formatting in Python

Tags: python, html, json

I am building a simple scraper that will go to a url, and pull the info from that page. I know, right? My issue is that when I pull the page info, it is not a traditional html with headers and formatting. It is simple text. Is there a way to only grab certain bits of information? I was going to try to export the page info, then read thru it and make another text file with only the bits I need!

The reason I need this is that I am trying to pull 13,000+ item ID's and organize them in a big ID dump! I was trying to convert it to JSON text format that the website usually uses. It is Moviestarplanet2, I have been tasked to look into this game.

This is my code so far(I know its basic!):

```
# Web scraper test
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html_to_json
import json
import requests
import time

IDNum = 688
url = 'https://us.mspapis.com/shopinventory/v1/shops/listings/' + str(IDNum)
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

I am needing to iron this problem out as early as possible as it is the primary function of this scraper. Any ideas or advice would be helpful! I am not advanced in python, but I can usually follow along pretty well. Sorry in advance if I ask any redundant or stupid questions.

I have tried using HTML to Json library, the built in json, googled for a good 2 hours and just slapping stuff in to see if it works. I'd like to actually learn instead of copy and pasting it from someone else and see why it does what it does.

EDIT! This is the data that I am trying to format!

```
{'id': '688', 'item': {'id': '912', 'type': 'item', 'singlePurchase': True, 'objectSource': 'curatedcontentitemtemplates', 'objectId': '596', 'resourceIdentifiers': [{'type': 'name', 'key': 'Neutral'}, {'type': 'graphics', 'key': 'default'}], 'tags': [{'hidden': False, 'id': '62', 'resourceIdentifiers': [{'type': 'label', 'key': 'TAG_MOODS'}, {'type': 'graphics', 'key': 'moods'}], 'type': 'category.animation', 'gameId': '5lxc'}, {'hidden': False, 'id': '85', 'resourceIdentifiers': [{'type': 'label', 'key': 'TAG_MOODS_BASIC'}, {'type': 'graphics', 'key': 'moods'}], 'type': 'subcategory.animation.62', 'gameId': '5lxc'}, {'hidden': False, 'id': '168', 'resourceIdentifiers': [{'type': 'label', 'key': 'TAG_FREE'}, {'type': 'graphics', 'key': 'free'}], 'type': 'category.artbooks', 'gameId': '5lxc', 'lookUpId': 'tag_free'}], 'lookUpId': 'f4b919d8-15f9-4dae-964f-bd9262db0a5b', 'additionalData': {'NebulaData': {'DefaultColors': '#FFFFFF', 'Snapshot': 'default_preview'}, 'MSP2Data': {'Loop': 'false'}}}, 'shopId': '8', 'price': {'currency': 'soft', 'salesPrice': 0.0, 'onSale': False}, 'lookUpId': '827e8ca7-60de-4d07-b0ae-61154d579b77'}
```

Answer (score 0):

That endpoint just returns JSON, so just call `resp.json()`.

```
import requests
import pprint

IDNum = 688
url = f'https://us.mspapis.com/shopinventory/v1/shops/listings/{IDNum}'
resp = requests.get(url)
resp.raise_for_status()
data = resp.json()
pprint(data["item"])  # or whatever
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much, I didn't know that I could have it laid out like that. the {IDNum} is a nice learn also. So that def made it easier to read, but its still basically all in one line. Maybe I should have been more specific, is there a way to make it multiline formatted? Like once I have the data, its not wrapping (i think is term?) or if I can just search each "web page" i pull for a certain string that appears in every page. Thanks for the reply, and you solved my first problem! This is just the bonus question ^^

Comment: Pprint (not print) already formats an object in a "nice" way for you. But the screen formatting of the data doesn't matter - now that you've parsed the JSON into a dict, you access the data you need off it and think about formatting later.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to print the Json on multiple lines:

```py
import json
import requests

IDNum = 688
url = "https://us.mspapis.com/shopinventory/v1/shops/listings/{}"

page = requests.get(url.format(IDNum))
data = page.json()

# print the Json on multiple lines:
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
{
    "id": "688",
    "item": {
        "id": "912",
        "type": "item",
        "singlePurchase": true,
        "objectSource": "curatedcontentitemtemplates",
        "objectId": "596",
        "resourceIdentifiers": [
            {
                "type": "name",
                "key": "Neutral"
            },
            {
                "type": "graphics",
                "key": "default"
            }
        ],
        "tags": [
            {
                "hidden": false,
                "id": "62",
                "resourceIdentifiers": [
                    {
                        "type": "label",
                        "key": "TAG_MOODS"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "graphics",
                        "key": "moods"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "category.animation",
                "gameId": "5lxc"
            },
            {
                "hidden": false,
                "id": "85",
                "resourceIdentifiers": [
                    {
                        "type": "label",
                        "key": "TAG_MOODS_BASIC"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "graphics",
                        "key": "moods"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "subcategory.animation.62",
                "gameId": "5lxc"
            },
            {
                "hidden": false,
                "id": "168",
                "resourceIdentifiers": [
                    {
                        "type": "label",
                        "key": "TAG_FREE"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "graphics",
                        "key": "free"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "category.artbooks",
                "gameId": "5lxc",
                "lookUpId": "tag_free"
            }
        ],
        "lookUpId": "f4b919d8-15f9-4dae-964f-bd9262db0a5b",
        "additionalData": {
            "NebulaData": {
                "DefaultColors": "#FFFFFF",
                "Snapshot": "default_preview"
            },
            "MSP2Data": {
                "Loop": "false"
            }
        }
    },
    "shopId": "8",
    "price": {
        "currency": "soft",
        "salesPrice": 0.0,
        "onSale": false
    },
    "lookUpId": "827e8ca7-60de-4d07-b0ae-61154d579b77"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't realize I basically had it right in front of me! Thanks again!